# grunt-exec doesn't recognize a custom function defined in bash

Tags: javascript, bash, gruntjs, grunt-exec

**Grunt version**: 
CLI - v1.2.0
local - v1.0.1

I'm using grunt-exec to start a local DynamoDB server. I'm doing this by creating a custom function in `.bashrc` then calling it inside grunt-exec. I also tried explicitly creating an alias, which didn't fix it.

**~/.bashrc**

```
runDynamo () {
    java -Djava.library.path=~/DynamoDBServer/DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar ~/DynamoDBServer/DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb
}
```

**Gruntfile.js**

```
// ...
exec: {
    dynamo: {
        // Run DynamoDB locally at port 8000
        // This alias has been set during the inital installation
        command: "runDynamo"
    }
}
// ...
var mode = grunt.option("mode") || "test";
grunt.registerTask("run", ["exec:" + mode]);
```

When I run `grunt run --mode=dynamo`, I get the following error in stdout:

```
Running "exec:dynamo" (exec) task
>> /bin/sh: 1: runDynamo: not found
>> Exited with code: 127.
>> Error executing child process: Error: Process exited with code 127.
```

The command works fine when used directly in bash (i.e. `$ runDynamo`), so I'm not sure why `grunt-exec` isn't working here.

Comment: IIRC, `~/.bashrc` is only sourced for interactive bash sessions (those either executed by `login` or run as `bash -i`. It's almost certain `grunt` will not be running `bash` in interactive mode (or might not even be using `bash` at all) when it forks a shell internally. [More info here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html). You can use `BASH_ENV` to set up a file for bash to source from there or wrap `grunt` in a script that will define that function for it.